# Is it possible to type casting an object to bool to return something depends on the state?

Tags: c#, casting, boolean, operator-overloading

I want to write a class to contain a `bool` value and a message. The message is used to explain why the class contains a false value. When I use this class, I would like to cast it to bool and it will return the bool value instead of get the property. Is this possible ?

```
public class ReturnResult
{
    public ReturnResult(bool state, string message)
    {
        IsSuccess = state;
        ErrorMessage = message;
    }

    public bool IsSuccess
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

I want to do the following

```
ReturnResult rr = CallSomeFunction(a,b,c);

if ((bool) rr) {
  // it is good
}
else {
  // it is bad
}
```

Comment: Why not do if(rr.IsSuccess) ?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to use the solution @auburg provided. It's straight forward, easy to read and doesn't imply that one has to know about the different types of ```ReturnResult``` depending on the state.

Comment: just out of curiosity: would that imply that you also would like to cast it to `(string)` to get the `ErrorMessage` ?

Comment: hi Monh Zhu, No because i thought it is confusing.

Comment: alright, btw, if you want to address someone directly then use a **@** before the name, then the person will get notified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you can override the `true` operator.

```
public class ReturnResult
{
    public ReturnResult(bool state, string message)
    {
        IsSuccess = state;
        ErrorMessage = message;
    }
    public bool IsSuccess
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static bool operator true(ReturnResult returnResult) => 
        returnResult.IsSuccess;

    public static bool operator false(ReturnResult returnResult) => 
        !returnResult.IsSuccess;    // Alternatively, implement as
                                    // returnResult ? false : true,
                                    // avoiding duplication.

}
```

You also have to define a matching `false` operator. Now these lines will work:

```
ReturnResult rr = CallSomeFunction(a,b,c);
if (rr) // Succeeds if the operator returns true, so if rr.IsSuccess is true.
{
    // If it's good.
}
else 
{
    // If it's bad.
}
```

EDIT:
As Dmitry suggested, it's probably worth mentioning that you can also override the implicit conversion operator to `bool`:

```cs
public static implicit operator bool(ReturnResult returnResult) => 
    returnResult.IsSuccess;
```

While `true` and `false` are used in Boolean Expressions[^1], which at the time of this writing are limited to control statements and the `?:` ternary operator, the implicit conversion operator will also allow assignments like this:

```cs
ReturnResult rr = CallSomeFunction(a,b,c);
bool b = rr;
```

You might wonder which one is used in an `if` statement if all three of them are overloaded - the answer is that [the implicit conversion takes precedence, as per the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#boolean-expressions).

[^1]: And also during `&&` and `||` operators evaluation, if there are user-defined `&` and `|` operators defined on the type. For more info, [the spec is your friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#user-defined-conditional-logical-operators).

Comment: You could also mention to OP that this correct solution is actually longer than doing `if (rr.IsSuccess)` ...

Comment: It is not possible to implement a `bool operator`

Comment: @Stefan These are `true` and `false` operators. Both of them return `bool`. See the spec for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operators

Comment: Thank you for adding a reference

Comment: Programming is fun because there is always something new. 
Thank you very much V0ldek.

Comment: `public static implicit operator bool(ReturnResult value) => value != null && value.IsSuccess;` is another possibility

Comment: @Alex You could implement `IsSuccess` as a method: `public bool IsSuccess(out string errorMessage)`. This would work like a try parse, and you could get the 2 things that are connected together (the false result and the error message) delivered to the user you your method in 1 blow.

Comment: @MartinVerjans It adds a few lines to the class declaration, but saves you the `IsSuccess` call in every place you use it. Longer depends on the context. If this is a class used in many different places throughout the codebase, I can see an argument for overriding the operators. We could probably have a hundred-years-long dispute about whether that's Clean Code, but that's a matter of personal taste more than anything.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That is correct, I have added an edit with more details about that approach.

Answer (score -1):

it should work if you write it like this (i wouldn't cast):

```
ReturnResult rr = CallSomeFunction(a,b,c);
if (rr.IsSuccesss) {
  // it is good
}
else {
  // it is bad
}
```

Comment: yes. i know. I want to know is there a better approach.